# Unplugging home TV saves power?

Tags: power

I've tried to find recent articles about how to save electricity at home. I remember the most basic instruction was to [unplug everything that was not being used](http://greenfamily.about.com/od/Green-Family-Basics/tp/10-Ways-To-Reduce-Your-Familys-Carbon-Footprint.htm) at that moment.

My problem is that I don't find this recommendation on newer articles that often and I'm now in doubt if some devices may actually save more power by staying in "stand by" mode if turned on and off very often. (Obviously not talking about a refrigerator or home life-support systems, I'm referring to devices like home theaters, gaming consoles, and everything you could have at the tv-room in general).

Is the sentence "Unplugging appliances that aren't being used saves power." still valid for modern devices?

Comment: For interest: In the UK, all home wall-outlets are switched. So you don't have to unplug appliances that lack a true power-off switch, you can just switch them off at the wall-outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, many modern devices draw *standby* power even when "off".  This very common with TVs, VCRs, and other consumer audio and video gear.

If it has a remote that can turn it on, then it has to be drawing a little power all the time just to be able to receive and decode the signal from the remote at any time.  Other evidence of drawing standby power is that the equipment gets a little warm even when "off".  Clearly some power is being used then.

The EPA (here in the US) has rules for how much standby power a device is allowed to draw, at least to get the Energy Star certification.  However, most consumers don't think of looking for that, so lots of devices don't bother being Energy Star certified.  Even so, I've been surprised how much standby power such devices are allowed to draw, judging from the noticable warmth they produce when off.

I have a TV and cable box that both draw standby power.  The amount of warmth produced by the cable box is surprisingly high.  It's got to be several watts in my estimation.

I deal with this by plugging all these devices into a outlet strip with a switch.  When the setup is not in use, the outlet strip is off and therefore no power at all is drawn.  The downside is that the cable box takes a extra minute to boot up when turned on, but I don't consider that a big deal.  I don't mind turning it on a minute or two before I want to use it, or just waiting the minute it takes to boot up.

To be fair, put the power drawn into perspective relative to what the rest of your house draws.  Let's say all the standby power of whatever consumer entertainment equipment you have draws a total of 5 W.  Let's say you run it 2 hours/day, so by turning it fully off with a separate switch, you save 5 W for 22 hours per day.  That's 110 Wh/day, which is 40 kWh/year.  At $.13/kWh, that's a bit over $5/year.  I'd rather save the $5, and more importantly, the 40 kWh, in return for waiting a extra minute for the system to come on.  It just bothers me that it does that more than having to flick a switch twice per use does.  However, from a pure cost analisys, it's not that big a deal.

Comment: Also, if you live in a temperate climate and fit a thermostat to your heating, for most the year the standby power decreases your heating bill.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the sentence "Unplugging appliances that aren't being used saves
>   power." still valid for modern devices?

Yes, this is not limited to "older" devices. To make it easier on yourself, plug them into a power strip and use that to disconnect all of your devices.

The amount of standby power drawn is small but finite. This will depend on the device, however. The multimeter and oscilloscope next to me draw zero power when switched off (hard disconnect from the power lines), however the monitors in front of me draw power no matter what, even when switched off since they have a 'soft' power switch.

Take a look at this link to see a standby power experiment http://standby.lbl.gov/summary-table.html

Answer (score 1):

There are devices that have vampiric power, and some that have standby power. Vampiric power is power wasted without reason. Like a power charger left plugged into the wall with nothing charging. These probably add up to a few dollars a year.

Then there are devices with simple standby power, like your stove or microwave. The standby is mostly for the clock they have. Other devices use standby for more things. A tv uses it to save its settings, keep track of time, listen for the remote control, automatic dvr, and automatic turn on times. Unplugging it will disable all of that, and probably make you look for all your channels again.

Most modern tvs have a energy star rating. It will tell you how much power it uses in standby. The 3 or 5 bucks you spend a year on it is worth the convienence imho.